# How to open big endian encoding (ieee-be) with python?

Tags: python, numpy, file, binary, endianness

I have this matlab code that opens a .eeg file:

```
f_in=fopen(a_eegfile,'r','ieee-be');% open file where eeg data are with Big-endian encoding
```

It gives me a 1D matrix of doubles. (793456x1)

I am trying to do the same thing with python and numpy:

```
data_f = np.fromfile(os.path.join(root,folder,filename), dtype='>f8')
```

It works but I'm not getting the same matrix at all.
Probably a problem in the dtype argument but I can't find it.

Anyone could help?

See:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes-constru

https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#btrnibn-1-machinefmt

Comment: I tried using 
    print(struct.unpack('>d',data_f))
But I get a struct error saying 
    (struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes)

Comment: I tried using '>i1' and it's much better. 

Except for big values like 192 I get -64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end it was way eaiser than this:

```py
with open(os.path.join(root,folder,filename),'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
    data_f = np.array([x for x in data])
```

data_f now stores my (793456x1) matrix of integers.

```py
print(type(data_f),len(data_f), data_f.dtype)
```

gives me:

`<class 'numpy.ndarray'> 16695840 int32`

with np as numpy.

Hope this is Useful for someone.